# Location of Resharper SDK project template and samples

Tags: sdk, resharper

I am trying to write a plugin for Resharper 8.1.  The online SDK documentation makes reference to a Visual Studio project template and list of sample projects.  I cannot seem to locate them.  They are not downloaded as part of the Resharper 8.1 SDK NuGet package, and although I have found several links that claim to take you to the download page for the Resharper SDK, they only take you here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/

This has a link to the Resharper SDK on this page, but that only takes you to the NuGet repository (and once again the NuGet package does not appear to contain the project templates or samples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the old 8.x SDKs [from this site](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-). The SDKs include the old samples projects.

I haven't updated the samples to 9.0 yet - they'll be uploaded to JetBrains' GitHub page once I've done it.